# How to get the URL for an image thumbnail

Tags: views, theming

I'm using a view template to override how a field is displayed.

The field happens to be an attached image to the node.

I notice in the view it's configured to display the thumbnail - when overriding, how do I get the thumbnail?

(I'm using entity_metadata_wrapper )

**EDIT**

So based on the suggetions below I need to use image_style_url - how do I get the path to pass to it?

ie, how do I complete this code

```
$node = node_load($row->{$field->field_alias});
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $survey_node); 

// Field is called field_image

$path = ???

$thumbnail_url = image_style_url('thumbnail', $path)

print "<img src='" & $thumbnail_url & "'>"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use function [`image_style_url($style_name, $path)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7) to obtain proper path in Drupal 7.20 and later. `$path` is a path to an original file. Preferably output normal path, and make it a thumbnail in proper `.tpl.php` file.

If you need to do it in place that does not accept php functions and cannot alter it in template, you can consider disabling `itok` token. To do so, add following line to your settings.php

```
$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;
```

Then you can simply add `styles/thumbnail/public/` like Kevin says, and use path like `example.com/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/myimage.jpg` to get thumbnail of `example.com/sites/default/files/myimage.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

In your default/files you will see a styles folder containing the same structure and same name for the files. Those are all your image styles inclusive thumbs.

so *default/files/myimage.jpg*
has thumbnail
*default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/myimage.jpg*

Comment: You forgot `itok` security token.